Django TemplateView raising on production Server 500 error
I am using Django with a gunicorn server for serving the dynamic templates and also the static files with whitenoise.
The application runs in an Docker-Container with a postgresql Database.
When using the DEBUG = True in the setting files. The html using TemplateView class is displayed.
However, when changing to DEBUG = FALSE the server raises a 500 code. All the other pages are rendered and work. So I dont think it is an issue where I placed the html files.
Also the static files are beeing served by gunicorn correctly.
What I found out so far is that in the settings:
    #STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

Makes the difference...but how and why?
I was aked to create a MRE. So here it is and I hope it is fine like this.
To reproduce it the following is needed: a django project and docker.
In the settings I have a base.py and a test.py.
Here the base.py
"""
Django settings for RootApplication project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.dev20180114011155.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
print("BASE_DIR:", BASE_DIR)

DEBUG = False


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django core apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Third-party apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    #'pwa',  # Uncomment if you're using these
    #'webpush',

    # Custom apps
    'landing_page.apps.Landing_PageConfig',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'RootApplication.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS':  [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'RootApplication.wsgi.application'


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'api', 'locale'),  
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'landing_page', 'locale'),  
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = (
  ('de', _('German')),
  ('en', _('English')),
)


TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if not DEBUG:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    # Tell Django to use WhiteNoise to serve static files
    #STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #'firebase.authentication.FirebaseAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
}

Here is the extension of the base.py with a test.py
"""
Django settings for RootApplication2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.dev20180114011155.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from .base import *
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
# Add production-specific apps
INSTALLED_APPS += [
    
]

# Add production-specific middleware
MIDDLEWARE += [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',     # For serving static files efficiently in production
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',"https://0.0.0.0:8000"]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'RootApplication2.urls'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # Disable allowing all origins

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True  # Keep secure CSRF cookies

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [    
    "https://localhost:8080",
    "https://localhost:8000",
    "https://127.0.0.1:9000",
    "https://0.0.0.0:8000"]  # Trust only your production domain

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'RootApplication2',
        'USER': 'RootApplication2',
        'PASSWORD': 'somePass',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

To run it here is the docker-compose.yml
# Goal of this docker-compose is to set up a local test environment.

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: RootApplication
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somePass
      POSTGRES_DB: RootApplication
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"  # Correct port for PostgreSQL

  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.test
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"  # Exposing port 8000 to the host
    env_file:
      - .env.prod
    volumes:
      - .:/RootApplication  # Bind mount local directory to container directory
      - static_volume:/RootApplication/staticfiles  # Named volume for static files
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  static_volume:  # Global volume declaration for static files

Which is using the Dockerfile.test:
COPY requirements.txt /RootApplication/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Copy the project files
COPY . /RootApplication/
RUN echo "Listing contents of /RootApplication:" && ls -R /RootApplication
# Copy the entrypoint script
COPY entrypoint.sh /RootApplication/entrypoint.sh
# Ensure the entrypoint script has Unix-style line endings
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /RootApplication/entrypoint.sh
# Make the entrypoint script executable
RUN chmod +x /RootApplication/entrypoint.sh
# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000
# Use the entrypoint script to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["/RootApplication/entrypoint.sh"]

The entrypoint script look as follow:
#!/bin/sh

# Debugging: List directory contents
# echo "Listing /RootApplication directory contents:"
# ls -R /RootApplication

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

#Make migrations
python /RootApplication/manage.py makemigrations

#MIGRATE
python /RootApplication/manage.py migrate

# Create a superuser if specified
if [ "$DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME" ]; then
    echo "Creating superuser $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME"
    python /RootApplication/manage.py createsuperuser --noinput \
        --username $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME \
        --email $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL
fi


# Check the environment variable to decide which server to start
if [ "$DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT" = "development" ]; then
    echo "Starting development server"
    python /RootApplication/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
else
    echo "Starting production server with Gunicorn"
    exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 RootApplication.wsgi:application
fi

In Django I have the following url.py

app_name = 'landing_page'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
    path('help/', views.help_page.as_view(), name='help'),
    path('privacy/', views.privacy_page.as_view(), name='privacy'),
    path('<int:calculationproject_id>', views.Showproject, name='Showproject'),
    path('json/',views.profile, name ='profile'),
    path('fan/', views.add_items, name='add_items'),
]

Here is the code-snippet of the views.py:
class help_page(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'landing_page/help.html'

The html are really basic though.
I appreciate any help
